# How is the next badge determined?

Tags: support, profile-page

My "next badge" on the main site is Marshall. What is the algorithm to determine which next badge to "promote". I am only 20 reviews away from the next Steward badge. That is much more achievable than the 196 flags I need for the Marshall badge.

Is there some way to indicate that you are not going to do the "promoted" badge (now), so you get can get some more sensible suggestion from the next badge in the queue?

Comment: Hit the gear like button right next to the new badge and you can chose which badge you want to track.

Comment: I missed that button entirely. But it doesn't show the steward badge as an option, maybe because I already have seven of them. It only seems to shown not yet acquired badges

Comment: Not sure if the algorithm was published. My guess is that it's based on a completion percentage. So if you need to do something `n` times to get the badge, and you have `k`, the badges are sorted by `k / n`. That's consistent with the order I see in my profile. And based on what you see, it sounds like for badges that are awarded multiple times, they are not considered anymore once you have one of them.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yeah, and the secondary sort seems to be alphabetical (`k` would make more sense as a secondary sort IMO).

Comment: My personal guess would also take in consideration the fame of the badge, as a badge has been awarded to a lot of users, it gets a higher chance to be selected as the next badge recommanded

Comment: @RetoKoradi My next badge on meta is "excavator", which is at 0/1, which is 0% complete. There seems to be more to the algorithm.

Comment: Would be nice if I could 'target' a tag specific badge.

Comment: I thought the algorithm was based on how rare the badges were, as well? Or is that just the profile showing rare badges?

Comment: @RetoKoradi It looks like there is more to the default algorithm than the completion percentage. I thought it was that way at first since it chose my Strunk & White badge (60/80 btw) to be my target badge while another one of my profiles chose a badge with a smaller percentage.